# Translating a complex Sentence into set of SPO triple (RDF) (maybe with reification)

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, triples, reification

Having just started out in RDF and ontology, mainly in converting unstructured text to RDF (maybe manually), I found many examples for converting simple sentences to RDF triples [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820657/how-can-i-represent-a-5-tuple-in-rdf) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705888/rdf-representation-of-sentences) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51756934/how-to-represent-this-statement-in-rdf?rq=1), but not much about complex sentences (using adjectives or adverbs) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476051/representing-complicated-sentences-using-rdf-syntax).

Example of complex sentence: *Those kids who, with great pleasure, like chocolate ice-cream and those who like vanilla ice-cream, which of them is better?*

Never mind the meaning of the sentence, what is remarkable is the use of adjectives for ice-cream (chocolate, vanilla) and liking (with pleasure), and the comparison between the two types of kids (who is better) and a question. How do we represent such sentences as a collection of SPO triple (RDF) statements - so that it can take care of adjectives, or adverbs or comparisons or other operations?

S1: Kids - Liking - (ice-cream, flavor, Chocolate)
S2: Kids - Liking - (ice-cream, flavor, Vanilla)
S3: liking with pleasure
S4: better(S1+S3, S2+S3)

Is there a general way to approach translating such statements?Where should one look for some exploration in this direction - unstructured text to n-tuples? Maybe I am not asking the right questions - in that case please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: The new proposal for that is [RDF*](http://blog.liu.se/olafhartig/2019/01/10/position-statement-rdf-star-and-sparql-star/). You can see there what are the benefits over the traditional approaches - reification and singleton property.

Comment: that is research topic and there is no solution nor is there a general way. "Ontology extraction from text" or "from unstructured data" are the key phrase to search for. We did a lots of things in that direction, nowadays different methods with neural networks will be used and have impact.

Answer (score 3):

That is a very difficult question that you are asking, there is not a single way to represent "semantic" in a graphical or tree or linkage structure that is definitive standard.

Look for instance at [Google syntax parse](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/analyzing-syntax), [Link Grammar](https://www.abisource.com/projects/link-grammar/), [Spacy dependency parse trees](https://explosion.ai/demos/displacy) or [Stanford NLP parser](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml).

See this question that is somewhat related, gives an example of link grammar parse result: [How to translate syntatic parse to a dependency parse tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40447641/how-to-translate-syntatic-parse-to-a-dependency-parse-tree)

For more advanced approaches look at [multinet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MultiNet) and [natural language to first-order-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/808681/english-sentence-to-fol) kind of approaches.

> Where should one look for some exploration in this direction - unstructured text to n-tuples?

You can represent what ever you want with n-tuples or 3-tuples, the thing is to know what and how to represent.

Last thing, you can come up with you are annotations, they are tools to do it like https://prodi.gy/. Have a look at this question that is seemingly unrelated but I give an example representation of questions that might help you achieve some task https://stackoverflow.com/a/32670572/140837

Good luck!!

Answer (score 2):

Far from attempting to describe a gneric way for translating such statements I thought of how that concrete example sentence could be modelled in RDF triples.

That's my first (late night) draft:

```
@prefix : <https://example.org/> .

[] a :Question, :PreferenceQuestion;
   :option [ 
       a :GroupOfHumans;
       :ageGroup :young;
       :perfomingActivity [
          a :Activity, :LikingActivity;
          :mode :withPleasure;
          :object [
              :category :IceCream;
              :flavour :vanilla;
           ]
       ]
   ],
   [ 
       a :GroupOfHumans;
       :ageGroup :young;
       :perfomingActivity [
          a :Activity, :LikingActivity;
          :mode :withPleasure;
          :object [
              :category :IceCream;
              :flavour :chocolate;
           ]
       ]
   ].
```

This would be 23 triples using quite an expressive Question/Activity/IceCream ontology.